# list of blocks as text file

Tags: blockchain

Is there a reliable source where I can download the blockchain as a text file?  Or perhaps is it included in my bitcoin-qt folder after it synchronizes with the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly request it incrementally from bitcoind/Bitcoin-Qt using the `getblock` and `getblockhash` RPCs, but there is no file maintained with the actual full list.

Comment: Ah, alright, I'll write a little program to fill up a list as a text file. Thanks for the answer.